# Common Fields For Different Model in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am developing a system where I have created multiple types of users(seller, agent provider, buyer, etc) by extending the Django default user model (BaseUserManager). I need to create a  common Address model which can be associated with all users. For example buyer, seller can be used the same address field but the data will be different & I need to post the user information and address field during the registration. I have tried the manytomanyfield but it's not working. Need an idea about the common model for all users.

Comment: you can create a model with a common field for all models and then inherit from it

Comment: Create a separate Address model. Link the Address model to your User model using OnetoMany relationship. If this confusing, you can post your models and I will be able to help.

Comment: This lesson from the Django 4 Everybody course may help https://www.dj4e.com/lessons/dj4e_owned. It explains how multiple models can be built on the same model base class thus inheriting that model's suite of common fields.